# Get Bitbucket project to Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, bitbucket

I am very new to Bitbucket, trying Clone remote Java project to my local repository.

I have IntelliJ 2018, Ultimate edition and first thing I did was `VCS->Enable ..->Git`.

Now I am doing this : `VCS->Git->Remotes`.

I am getting "**Get Remotes**" window and I click on `+` sign.

Another window pops up: `Name : origin, URL : <I provide a URL for Bitbucket Repo>`.

I click "Ok".

I am getting this message: `Remote URL Test failed : unable to update URL base from redirection.`

Strange thing is I don't see ".git" files in any of Bitbucket repositories, like there is in GitHub or GitLab.

Comment: Bitbucket git url ends with `.git`. I think the problem in your url. Share us obfuscating some sensible parts. Also you can try to clone another [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/repo/all?name=java) or [github](https://github.com/StackExchange) repositories to validate if the problem in your machine, your ide, etc. Also I advice to use pure git commands and the IDE for developing things

Comment: @JRichardsz is right, it worth checking the URL itself. You can find correct one under "Clone" button on BitBucket website.
If you want to clone from IntelliJ, then you can go to Git menu | Clone. Or the same can be done from Welcome screen of IDE:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/set-up-a-git-repository.html#clone-repo

Comment: @Ruslan Kuleshov. Thank you, it worked perfectly fine after I got correct URL from BitBucket page. I was able to create New Project from Remote Repository.

Comment: Could you add the wrong url and how was obtained? This could help to new developers

Comment: I just did a stupid thing and picked up URL from the browser.